# What format does Xamarin store dates in Sqlite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, xamarin.android, epoch

When saving a standard `DateTime` from .NET into a SQLite table I get values like this saved:

`636183611669074150`

What exactly is this format? I am doing some bug fixing and would like to know the exact date held by the number without running my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DateTime.Ticks` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) says:

> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 (0:00:00 UTC on January 1, 0001, in the Gregorian calendar).